# Makeshift stand for large tablet

Tags: substitute-tool, technology, camping

I'm on a small holiday in a camping trailer, and amongst loads of other stuff I brought my iPad and a keyboard. But I *didn't bring a stand for my iPad*.

Do you have a suggestion for a makeshift stand which would allow to me to easily watch the screen (vertically) whilst typing on my keyboard, which is sturdy enough to allow touching and navigating the touch screen?

I do have quite a lot of utilities, stuff and tools available, so feel free to suggest any good stand options you'll have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After first just leaning against a larger box, where the iPad kept slipping when touched,  I considering using a silicone heat brick so it shouldn't slip.

Then I saw this picture frame just laying there, which when flipped around turned out to be almost of perfect width for my tablet. I then found a small box which when turned around fitted inside and gave a good angle.

[image: iPad on back of frame leaning against a box]

So for now, until even better ideas arises, this my current stand. But please submit other suggestions as I'd would like to see other ideas (and don't want to accept my own answer :-))

Answer (score 5):

If you have a decently large log and a camping hatchet, you could notch the log on the side, then split it so you have a ledge to rest the tablet on and a back to support it.

Comment: I like the idea, though I'm in a camping trailer, not in the great outdoors.  :-D